# Symfony set up in iis

Tags: php, symfony, iis-7

I have a iis development server set up and i have just successfully downloaded and installed symfony2 which is placed in the web root of this server and im trying to create a bundle within my project and i seem to be getting this error message in the dos box:

**`the program cant start because of php5.dll is misisng from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem`**

even though the dll is in the directory of the php folder on the C: drive on my computer. 
and yes i entered php app/console generate:bundle into the cmd box.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated

Comment: How did you install PHP on IIS? How did you install Symfony, and was it success? I mean could you see the defaule ACME project in you localhost output?

Comment: i installed php by getting the msi and configuring the exe in the iis control panel and yes it was a success installing symfony2 as i was getting the successful install message

Comment: I would recommend to install **Microsoft Web Platform Installer** first; then search for *PHP 5.4>* and *PHP Manager for IIS* in the productions list and add/install it. Before doing this plz unistall previous installed PHP for IIS. This is much safe and reliable than installing php manually, specially that it will do IIS configuration for PHP automatically

Answer (score 0):

It seems the PHP was not installed successfully or IIS was not configured correctly for the available PHP.

I would recommend to unistall the previous PHP on IIS and install **Microsoft Web Platform Installer** first; then search for *PHP 5.4>* and *PHP Manager for IIS* in the productions list and add/install them.

This is much safe and reliable than installing php manually, specially that it will do IIS configuration for PHP automatically